Google Sheets : Spreadsheet Service Timeout
My sheet has around 200 tabs. My code is listing all the sheet names in a new sheet.
Here's my code.
function writeSheetNamesInBatches() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get the "Non Team Sheets" sheet
  const nonTeamSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Non Team Sheets");

  // Get the list of extra sheets from the "Non Team Sheets" sheet
  const extraSheets = nonTeamSheet.getRange("A1:A10").getValues().flat();

  // Create a set for quick lookup of extra sheet names
  const extraSheetSet = new Set(extraSheets);

  // Get all sheet names in the spreadsheet, excluding the extra sheets
  const sheetNames = ss.getSheets()
                      .map(sheet => sheet.getName())
                      .filter(name => !extraSheetSet.has(name));
  const batchSize = 50;

  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet Names');
  if (sheet) {
    ss.deleteSheet(sheet);
  }

  // Create a new sheet to write the sheet names
  const newSheet = ss.insertSheet('Sheet Names');

  // Calculate the number of rows and columns needed
  const numColumns = Math.ceil(sheetNames.length / batchSize);
  const numRows = Math.min(sheetNames.length, batchSize);

  // Initialize the 2D array with empty arrays for each row
  const data = Array.from({ length: numRows }, () => Array(numColumns).fill(''));

  // Fill the 2D array with sheet names
  sheetNames.forEach((name, index) => {
    const rowIndex = index % batchSize;
    const colIndex = Math.floor(index / batchSize);
    data[rowIndex][colIndex] = name;
  });

  // Write the entire 2D array to the new sheet in one go
  newSheet.getRange(1, 1, numRows, numColumns).setValues(data);
}


But I keep getting the same error. It gets timed out without writing anything in the "Sheet Names"
I made sure that 5M cell limit has not exceeded. I also tried batch operations and entering data row by row using SpreadsheetApp.flush(). Neither of the approaches worked.

The cell limt is 10M, not 5M. It was increased some time ago.
